# ion-item ng-repeat - Show current record number

Tags: ionic-framework

Any ideas how I can show the current record number or index of an item?
If my list contains 100 items,  How can I show  1, 2, 3, on the heading?
or Show the current Item (index?) next to the item?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `{{$index}}` to display the current record number when iterating through a collection with ng-repeat.

See also: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I would appreciate if you then could mark the answer as the best answer.